# Python - If element is in list, return another unique element

Tags: python, python-2.7

(This is Python 2.7.10)

I am traversing through a list of sublists that like this:

```py
for x in words:
    for subs in bigLsts:
        if x in subs:
            print() # Here, I want to print a different word in subs that is not the same word
```

`bigLsts` is a list of word lists formatted like this:

```py
bigLsts = [
   ["herro", "hewwo", "holas"],
   ["woah", "woahwa", "whatda"]
]
```

If `x` is in the `subs`, how can I print another word in the sublist that is not the same word as `x`? So, if `x == "hewwo"` how can I print either `"herro"` or `"holas"` but not `"hewwo"`

I have some solutions like generating a random number that does not include the index of that element, but solutions like that feel a bit clunky to me. Is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: Make copy of `subs`. Remove `x` from the copy. Select a random element of the copy and print it.

Comment: @Barmar. That sounds even klunkier

Comment: Can you very specifically define "klunky", e.g., by showing what you've tried and explaining what you didn't like about it? Right now this is very much opinion based, in my opinion.

Comment: @Barmar. I think there's a compromise: use a generator and apply `min` with a random number as the key.

Answer (score 1):

Generating a random number that is not the index of the element does not have to be clunky. One simple way to do it is to generate a number that is in the range `[0, len(subs) - 2]` and add one if the number is greater than or equal to the index you want to avoid. You can use the fact that python booleans are a subtype of integers to make the computation very simple:

```
ind = random.randrange(0, len(subs) - 1)
ind += ind >= subs.index(x)
print(subs[ind])
```

That being said, you can use an even simpler formulation, courtesy of [this unrelated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642337/2988730):

```
min((i for i in subs if i != x), key=lambda x: random.random())
```

The idea is to take the element with the minimum uniformly randomly generated key. The generator automatically handles skipping the element you want to skip without doing an `index` lookup or ever mentioning indices at all.

Answer (score 0):

In your inner loop, you can consider using the following `try` statement (to **replace** the `if x in subs`):

```
from random import randrange
try:
     idx = subs.index(x)
     while True:
          a = randrange(0, len(subs))
          if a != idx:
               break
     print(subs[a])
except ValueError:
     pass
```

The `try` suite tries to find the index in `subs` with corresponding element equal to the word `x`.

- In the event that `x` is not found, a `ValueError` is raised and we quietly ignore it.
- In the event that `x` is found, `idx` is assigned the corresponding index. Then, we assign a random integer in `[0, len(subs) - 1]` (i.e. the set of valid indices for `subs`) to `a` until `a` is not equal to `idx`. Once `a` is not equal to `idx`, we break out of the loop and print `subs[a]`.

Drawing inspiration from @Mad Physicist, it would be better if the `try` suite were replaced with

```
a = randrange(0, len(subs) - 1)
a += a >= subs.index(x)
```

which assigns `a` to a random integer in `[0, len(subs) - 1)` and then increments `a` by 1 if `a >= idx` is true; otherwise (i.e. if `a < idx` is true), `a` is unchanged. If this change is made, the `try` statement becomes

```
try:
     a = randrange(0, len(subs) - 1)
     a += a >= subs.index(x)
     print(subs[a])
except ValueError:
     pass
```

A slight optimization would be to simply catch all exceptions with `except:` (replacing `except ValueError:`). See, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898601/any-specific-reason-to-specify-the-type-of-exception/71901571#71901571). The gist of it is that if an except clause has an expression (here, `ValueError`), it needs to be evaluated and tested against the raised exception from the `try` suite. An expression-less except clause (as in `except:`) does not have to do this additional step. I would not recommend making catching all exceptions a habit, however -- it is context-specific.

**Example Session**

Suppose that

```
words = ["green", "eggs", "and", "ham", "hewwo", "woahwa"]
bigLsts = [['herro', 'hewwo', 'holas'], ['woah', 'woahwa', 'whatda']]
```

A session might yield output

```
herro
whatda
```

Comment: You only ever print if `x` is found, so the try-catch is overkill

Comment: @Mad Physicist I don't follow. Could you elaborate a little? If that `try` statement is in the inner loop and we remove the `try` and `except` the code above would generate `ValueError`s. The `if x in subs` is not part of my code.

Comment: If you're suggesting to replace `if x in subs:` with the `try`, that's fine.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it!

Comment: If you're going to use walrus: `a = ((a := randrange(0, len(subs) - 1)) >= idx) + a`. No need for a conditional

Comment: But given that the question is tagged 2.7, you really shouldn't be using walrus anywhere in your answer

Comment: @Mad Physicist Good point with the Walrus operator. I didn't realize OP said Python 2. Though since we are on the topic of Python3 versus Python2, I believe True and False is not guaranteed to be equal to 1 and 0 in Python2.x.

Comment: Of course it is: bool has been a subclass of int since forever: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8169049/2988730

Comment: Okay I saw the first sentence of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the)  and obviously did not read further :P. I also did not want to do your `+= ind >= subs.index(x)` because (1) I thought it was neat (2) would not have been my first idea (3) did not want to steal your limelight!

Comment: As someone who also writes in C, I welcomed the Walrus operator as it can improve readability in some situations such as this IMO.